# Can you remove dead wiki links in the "See Also" section of a FogBugz case?

Tags: wiki, hyperlink, fogbugz

We have a couple cases in FogBugz that have a link to an old wiki via the ***See Also*** section. No where in these cases is there a link in the edited text (the normal section where you enter your text), so I'm assuming the link was created through the wiki article (using the ***Case ###*** linking method). However, the wiki article appears to be deleted (as clicking the link says ***This article does not exist***). Is there any way to actually remove the link from these cases to the non-existent wiki?

Thanks

UPDATE:

[Here's](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.43555.2) a link to the question on the FogBugz Technical Support forum.

UPDATE 2:

They have fixed this issue and will be releasing it in the next FogBugz update. Many thanks to Ben Kamens, Rich Armstrong, Joel Spolsky and the rest of Fog Creek!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a good idea to ask this one on the [FogBugz tech support forum](http://support.fogcreek.com/?fogbugz). Likely you'll have to go into the DB directly and edit the records to remove the links. That's my thought.

Comment: Ya that was where I was originally going to post this question. I thought I'd give the SO community first dibs. Looks like I'm not getting any other responses, so I'll have to take the support forum route.

Comment: Looks like it can't be done (without direct db editing). They are looking into in the FB Tech Support Forum. Maybe it'll be part of FB 7.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably aware of this, but this bug was fixed in FogBuz version 7 (possible patched in version 6).